# How to display combo box loading message in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, radgrid

We are loading RadGridView inside the RadComboBox. When we are clicking on the combo box then its take time. I think it's take time due to RadGridView. RadGridView taking time in the data binding so combo box does not populating immediately. We want if item source has not been populated yet, pop up a box “Please wait while the product list is loaded….”. If possible, load the list at that point, then close the box.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="partIdRadComboBox" Grid.Column="1" Height="32" Width="70" Margin="0,10,4,4" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                             EmptyText="-" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="True" AllowDrop="False"
                                             IsTextSearchEnabled="True" OpenDropDownOnFocus="True" FontSize="15" InputScope="Number">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadComboBoxItem">
                    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="RadGridView1" ShowGroupPanel="False" CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                                            RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                            IsFilteringAllowed="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                                            Height="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            RowStyle="{StaticResource ComboboxRowStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding PartID}" Header="Part ID" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ShopID}" Header="Shop ID" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UnitRate}" Header="Base $" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding BookUnitRental}" Header="Base Rent $" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" />
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBoxItem.Template>
        </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
    <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ie:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectHighlightedProductCommand}"/>
        </ie:EventTrigger>
    </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: `RadGridView` has an event `LayoutLoaded`, but I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for because it has no documentation. If it is then you can start your window with `Please wait` on other thread and close it when `LayoutLoaded` fires.

Comment: We need to display message when user clicking on the combo box. Any solution of this question.

Comment: I think Listview showing on the click of combo box so how to bind data into listview on the loading time. Have you any idea behind this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a solution to your problem. I would worry about when to hide the loading screen. So you could start with empty object that is bound to your list. Then on button click you would assign some data to it and display `Loading Data` and then you would have to catch event when loading is finished.